# Missing File After Removing Pods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

After I removed a couple of pods, Xcode suddenly shows 1007 warnings. It's missing the pod files that I just removed. Here is a 
[image]

I looked up many answers but non of them is helpful. What would be a good solution in this case? Thank you!

Comment: "What would be a good solution in this case?"  Put the pods back.

Comment: I will not put the pods back.

Comment: I got the same problem: any solution so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tons of research, finally I realize that I should refresh status in the source control tab.

[image]

Since my files are deleted but the project is hosted on GitHub, I have to update my repo otherwise the project is still asking for the old header files.